# Display items in a list with font colors in vba

Tags: excel, vba

It was tough making a title for this question...

I have a list (ever changing) that may look similar to this...

```
DS100
DS100
DS200
DS200
DS300
DS300
```

New items may/will be added that may/will be the same or different from an existing item. A sort routine puts them all in order like above. I then need to change the color of the font when a difference is found.
For example: DS100 - Blue font, DS200 - Red font, DS300 - Back to blue font.

Each section may be 1 to ?? rows of entries. I want to tell at a glance, where the items change by changing the font color at the end of the sort routine. (Clear as mud?)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use coloured fonts or coloured backgrounds?  If font, you need a selection of dark colours.  If backgrounds, you need a selection of light colours.

Next pick some colours you like are which are sufficiently different to give adequate contrast.

Having selected the colours, you want from the palette, go back to the palette and select “More Colours” then “Custom” for each colour.  This will show the red, green and blue components which you have to record.

This is my list of colours:

[image: My colour table]

I have selected four dark and four light colours.  You only need two but you can have as many as you wish.  I have not put a lot of thought into my selection of colours, so I doubt this list will appeal to you.

Next load this information to an array:

```
 Dim Colours() As Variant
 Colours = VBA.Array(RGB(0, 0, 0), RGB(192, 0, 0), RGB(0, 32, 96), RGB(55, 86, 35))
 ‘ or
 Colours = VBA.Array(RGB(248, 203, 173), RGB(255, 230, 153), RGB(180, 198, 231), RGB(169, 208, 142))
```

' You cycle though these colours so:

InxColour = LBound(Colours)

```
  'For Each row
    'If need new colour because current cell different from previous
      InxColour = InxColour + 1
      If InxColour > UBound(Colours) Then
        InxColour = LBound(Colours)
      End If
    End If
    'Colour cell
  Next
```

To colour a cell, use one of the following:

```
.Cells(Row, Column).Font.Color = Colours(InxColour)
.Cells(Row, Column).Interior.Color = Colours(InxColour)
```

Answer (score 0):

What I came up with is this:

```
Sub ColrFonts()
Dim rn As Long
Dim LastSel As String
Dim MyCounter As Integer

' Make entire column font = black
Range("A:A").Select
With Selection.font
    .Color = vbBlack
End With

rn = getlast1("A") ' function to find last row number used
MyCounter = 1

LastSel = Range("A4").Value

For a = 5 To rn
    LastSel = Range("A" & a - 1).Value
    Range("A" & a).Select
    If Range("A" & a) = LastSel Then
        With Selection.font
            If MyCounter = 1 Then
                .Color = vbBlack
            End If
            If MyCounter = 2 Then
                .Color = vbRed
            End If
        End With
    End If
    If Range("A" & a) <> LastSel Then
        MyCounter = MyCounter + 1
        If MyCounter = 3 Then MyCounter = 1
            With Selection.font
            If MyCounter = 1 Then
                .Color = vbBlack
            End If
            If MyCounter = 2 Then
                .Color = vbRed
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next a
End Sub
```

I put this together after I posted my question.
I can "plod" through and usually come up with something but,
I was hoping there would be a more efficient way of doing it.

Comment: Please do not select each cell.  Select is much slower than .Cell(Row, Column).  You can reduce the duration a little by adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the top.